# Macro that moves data between 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that takes data from one sheet and puts it into another sheet (RMA). It automatically creates a new line under the previous one. However column `A` in the RMA sheet has data in it and the macro looks at column `A` and adds the new line under the last number in column `A`. I want it to discount that column and add it next to the number. Can this be done? Below is some of the code that puts the Data in in the RMA sheet.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RMA").Activate
Worksheets("RMA").Select
Worksheets("RMA").Range("a8").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("RMA").Range("a8").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("RMA").Range("a8")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = invoiceNumber
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = customerRef
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = customerName
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = customerCountry
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = customerCompany
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific with this statement `I want it to discount that column and add it next to the number. `? Do you want it to be based on the rowset in a different column? Or do you want it to be based on Column A, but move one row down, after the last number?

Comment: When I start the macro instead of creating a new row underneath B8 it begins the row underneath the last value in the A column. I basically have a load of numbers in column A and I want the row to be created next to the number!

Comment: Thanks. The simple answer is to change all references of `A8` in your code to `B8`, so long as there are no blanks cells in column B. However, I placed an answer below as well to give you an optional code approach, that may be more simpler and help your code run faster in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try What is Below. May be simpler to read and faster as it doesn't `select` any objects, but works directly with them. This code works if there are no blank cells in column B, from row 8 until the end.

```
Dim wks as Worksheet
Set wks = Sheets("RMA")

With wks
     Dim RowCount as Long
     RowCount = .Range("B8").End(xlDown).Row + 1

     .Cells(RowCount,1) = invoiceNumber
     .Cells(RowCount,2) = customerRef
     ...
```